# Finding Eigenvalues of a 3x3 Matrix (7.12-17)

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

Please check my work in finding eigenvalues for the following problem. I am working out of the textbook *Advanced Engineering Mathematics* by Erwin Kreyszig, 1988, John Wiley & Sons.

For reference the following identity is given because some textbooks reverse the formula having $\lambda$ subtract the diagonal elements instead of subtracting $\lambda$ from the diagonal elements:

$$ det(A - \lambda I) = 
\begin{vmatrix}
    13-\lambda & 0 & -15 \\
    -3 & 4-\lambda & 9 \\
    5 & 0 & -7-\lambda \\
\end{vmatrix} = 0
$$
Taking the center column we have:
$$
(4-\lambda)
\begin{vmatrix}
    13-\lambda & -15 \\
    5 & -7-\lambda \\
\end{vmatrix} \\
= (4-\lambda)[(13-\lambda)(-7-\lambda) + 5(15)] = 0 \\
= (4-\lambda)(\lambda^2 - 6\lambda - 91 + 75) = 0 \\
= (4-\lambda)(\lambda^2 - 6\lambda -21) = 0 \\
= -\lambda^3 + 10\lambda^2 - 24\lambda + 21\lambda - 84 = 0 \\
= \lambda^3 - 10\lambda^2 + 3\lambda + 84 = 0 \\
$$
Using an online calculator the characteristic equation factors into:
$$
\lambda^3 - 10\lambda^2 + 3\lambda + 84 = 0 \\
(\lambda - 4)(\lambda^2 - 6\lambda - 21) = 0 \\
$$
But answer in text is 
$$
\begin{align*}
\lambda_1 = 8 \qquad \lambda_2 = 4 \qquad \lambda_3 = -2 \\
\end{align*}
$$
**Question: Although I can get $\lambda = 4$ out of the factored equation there is no way to get the other two eigenvalues. I suspect my algebra. Where did I go wrong?**

Comment: Your error is in = $$(4-\lambda)(\lambda^2 - 6\lambda - 91 + 75) = 0 \\
= (4-\lambda)(\lambda^2 - 6\lambda \color{red}{-21}) = 0$$. It should be $\color{blue}{-16}$  and then it factors well to give you the required answerr

Comment: And then instead of multplying out $(4-\lambda)(\lambda^2-6\lambda -16)$, just factor $(4-\lambda)(\lambda-8)(\lambda +2)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your error is in the step $$(4-\lambda)(\lambda^2 - 6\lambda - 91 + 75) = 0 \\
= (4-\lambda)(\lambda^2 - 6\lambda \color{red}{-21}) = 0$$ It should be $\color{blue}{-16}$  and then it factors well to give you the required answer